# I am having a mixup with these algorithms

Tags: ios, parse-platform

I am getting users profile names / group names from my database (firebase)... So originally, I was just passing parse my objectId belonging to the user whos picture I was looking for, But now I am having mix ups where I am having group class member pictures showing up for user class people...

Hers the JSON of the first database

```
  "-KCvEE45IoE1AjDbnRK7" : {
      "counter" : 0,
      "date" : "2016-03-17T19:24:21",
      "description" : "Travis Tubbs",
      "groupId" : "js837yUMs0xIClIaB3Lb",
      "lastMessage" : "AwG1wCdnaYSm+GmeX5K7QV3qNKKBQdTtnY7rVwaFDrgHjB9viH5husSJRAk6SNIMCMMKAsFUhSgT/eJmwM04hZzwoVQc1RqqnC9vV91qAhUGVw==",
      "members" : [ "js837yUMs0", "xIClIaB3Lb" ],
      "password" : "h6vfwBTeju",
      "profileId" : "js837yUMs0",
      "recentId" : "-KCvEE45IoE1AjDbnRK7",
      "type" : "private",
      "userId" : "xIClIaB3Lb"
    },
    "-KCvSmzlpADYmTsYMzCl" : {
      "counter" : 0,
      "date" : "2016-03-17T19:26:13",
      "description" : "CNN",
      "groupId" : "KfMfFI9VXe",
      "lastMessage" : "AwHjItVn04SHxR3v281XlAm/KUzs8NGv+09OxWRfkkVO1ibeTUpAmSpiw5amQaI+GP3+1tIqPnAzpWyonE6BlsROs/Mx6zTLr3dzEZWwxq8Rgg==",
      "password" : "inQTldUXaZ",
      "profileId" : "js837yUMs0",
      "recentId" : "-KCvSmzlpADYmTsYMzCl",
      "type" : "group",
      "userId" : "js837yUMs0"
    },
```

and here is my parse queries

```
  if([recent[@"type"]  isEqual: @"private"]) {

    PFQuery *query = [PFQuery queryWithClassName:PF_USER_CLASS_NAME];
    [query whereKey:PF_USER_OBJECTID equalTo:recent[@"profileId"]];
    [query setCachePolicy:kPFCachePolicyCacheThenNetwork];
    [query findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock:^(NSArray *objects, NSError *error)
    {
        if (error == nil)
        {
            PFUser *user = [objects firstObject];
            [AFDownload start:user[PF_USER_PICTURE] complete:^(NSString *path, NSError *error, BOOL network)
            {
                if (error == nil) imageUser.image = [[UIImage alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:path];
            }];
        }
    }];
    }
    if([recent[@"type"]  isEqual: @"group"])
    {
    PFQuery *query2 = [PFQuery queryWithClassName:PF_GROUP_CLASS_NAME];
    [query2 whereKey:PF_GROUP_NAME equalTo:recent[@"description"]];
    [query2 setCachePolicy:kPFCachePolicyCacheThenNetwork];
    [query2 findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock:^(NSArray *objects, NSError *error)
     {
         if (error == nil)
         {
             PFUser *group = [objects firstObject];
             [AFDownload start:group[PF_GROUP_LOGO] complete:^(NSString *path, NSError *error, BOOL network)
              {
                  if (error == nil) imageUser.image = [[UIImage alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:path];
              }];
         }
     }];
    }
```

Again, it seems as though I have a logic problem because lets say that I have a group "Foo" sometimes it will show the picture of user "Roger Waters" or as well, group "Bar" will have its picture show as group "espn"s picture

Comment: I don't know what is supposed to be happening. Is that JSON correct or incorrect? Or is that just a sample of the data? Also, how are you running the code? Should it be `group` or `private`?

Comment: Fogmeister, the JSON is correct, it is just to show context to the parse algorithms.  @matt, I have been debugging it, and if you look at my if statements and my question, then it literally makes 0 sense as to why this is happening. I am thinking that parse is handling something be hind the scenes that I am not following.

Comment: After looking at my code, I believe my issue might be in my cache policy with parse. not in my logic. Thoughts?

Answer (score 0):

I figured out the problem with my code...

It was neither a logic error or a cache error...

It was 2 different artifacts where I had a value that existed in one of my databases, but then it did not exist in my other database so it was just sending a null value in my cloud code and breaking so that I wasn't seeing an error app side.